# How to identify outliers in a zero-inflated binomial distribution of count data

Tags: outliers, count-data

I have some data in which the researchers measured the number of times someone lied on a particular day (n=1000). I would like to identify outliers- those people who lied much more than the rest of the sample (assuming no measurement error). The count data is quite zero-inflated, as most people reported no lying or very few lies. Here are the frequencies:

0- 620

1- 147

2- 84

3- 44

4- 24

5- 16

6- 11

7- 9

8- 8

9- 5

10- 8

11- 2

12- 2

13- 1

14-2

15-1

16-1

19-1

20-2

22-1

26-1

27-1

30-1

38-2

39-1

40-1

41-1

45-1

53-1

134-1

It appears to be a negative binomial distribution. My understanding is that one is unable to normalize such a zero-inflated count distribution and use the typical 1.5(IQR) rule for identifying outliers. So, how would one identify the outliers in such a distribution?

Comment: What is the goal of the analysis? Why do you need to identify outliers?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the boxplot outlier criterion is not going to be much help
for your data. It may be instructive to investigate why this is so.

First, I tried to reclaim a list `x` of 1000 reported numbers of lies, as shown below. (It wouldn't hurt to proofread my data entry.)

```
nr.lies = c(0:16, c(19,20,22,26,27,30,38,39,40,41,45,53,134))
counts = c(620,147,84,44,24,16,11,9,8,5,8,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,
           1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
x = rep(nr.lies, counts)
length(x)
[1] 1000
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   0.000   1.651   1.000 134.000
```

The usual boxplot outlier criterion uses the interquartile range (IQR).
For your data, $\mathrm{IQR} = Q_3 - Q_1 = 1 - 0 = 1.$ So anything larger than $Q_3 + 1.5(\mathrm{IQR}) = 1 + 1.5(1) = 2.5$ will be a boxplot 'ourlier' in your data.

```
boxplot(x, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Many distributions produce such highly right-skewed data that outlier
detection by boxplots is not useful. Yours seems to be among them.

Your highest six observations are as follows:

```
tail(sort(x))
[1]  39  40  41  45  53 134
```

It is not clear to me whether all six of even these most extreme
observations ought to be called outliers. So I can't see that an outlier-detection rule based on quantiles would be helpful.

The one response 134 seems
fanciful and I might doubt whether that was intended as a serious
response. [In order to tell a lie 134 times during the waking hours
of a day would mean one lie every 7 or 8 minutes. I can't imagine
that even a few politicians would aspire to lie at that rate.]

Before trying to identify outliers in such a dataset, I think you
need to formulate clearly why you need to identify outliers, and
what you intend to do about them when you find them. Removal of
outliers from a sample without clear evidence of an error in producing
or recording the data has been consistently deprecated on this site.
[So, if `134` is revealed to be a typo for `13`, it should certainly be removed from the dataset.]

Comment: Following up on the last sentence, if `134` is just an inconvenient number, removing it may be unwise.

Comment: @Dave: Right: Especially, in such a large dataset, removal may not only be unwise, it may also be pointless: The mean of all 1000 is 1.65, the mean of the remaining 999, after removing `134`, is 1.52. And the median is 0 either way.

Comment: I wonder if it would affect conditional means, though, when you do the regression.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BruceET 's answer, just adding some more points.

There is no standard computational definition of outlier -- even in a normal distribution. The 1.5 IQR rule is sometimes a useful guideline, but sometimes not. For the boxplots, it was devised in the days when a data set of several hundred was big (I think John Tukey came up with it, he certainly popularized it).

If you generate 1000 data points from a normal distribution then you will get quite a few supposed "outliers"; e.g.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000)
Upper <- mean(x) + 1.5*IQR(x)
Lower <- mean(x) - 1.5*IQR(x)
Outside <- sum(x > Upper) + sum(x < Lower)
Outside
```

gives 53 observations that are outliers.

An outlier is a "surprising observation" but in order to evaluate the degree of surprise, you have to figure out what you expect.

134 is surprising. Why? Not so much because it is far from the next highest value, but because a) It's very specific. When people report numbers like this, they usually round them. It's hard to imagine that someone would know that they told 134 lies in a day (and not 130 or 137 or something).  b) It's difficult on purely practical grounds. If the person was awake for 16 hours, that's 8.4 lies per hour, or a lie every 7 minutes.That's not totally impossible, but it seems very weird. Some of the other numbers seem like outliers as well.

Another question is why you want to identify these and what you will do about them.  My opinion is that, unless an observation is clearly a data entry error or an impossible value (e.g. a 6 meter tall human), removing them is a bad idea. There are lots of robust measures that can be used. (You don't say what analysis you are doing, so it's impossible to suggest specific methods).

Comment: I agree that boxplots don’t seem to work here. The purpose of my question is this-  in the social sciences, where deception is studied, there Are consistent findings that most people are fairly honest, while a small subset do most of the lying. Sort of a Pareto principle. I am trying to figure out a statistical method for separating those prolific liars from the rest of the group, if indeed there is A logical reason to separate them. Identifying them as statistical outliers would be a first step, I think.

Comment: I would look into cluster analysis.