# BEST POSSIBLE WAY to determine significantly high values within zero-inflated univariate continuous distributions

Tags: descriptive-statistics, outliers, anomaly-detection, boxplot, interquartile

I have more than 50 different distributions, corresponding to 50 different kind of customers, who spend their money in a certain way within a period, being this amount the **single variable** of interest.

I want to find, in each of these 50 distributions, THE BEST POSSIBLE WAY/or the least bad one to **determine a set of significantly high values** for this single expense variable, despite the very **high concentration of 0s**, something which is very common in all distributions (ranging around 60-90% zeros in most cases).

I do not post graphs because Box Plots are similar to those in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466324/how-to-identify-outliers-in-a-zero-inflated-binomial-distribution-of-count-data) replies, but none of the answers have provided a solution to my problem. Like in the post, the usual **upper bounds Box Plot outliers criteria do not work**: in **most cases the upper bound of the IQR is 0**, so many customers spending 5 or $10 are considered outliers.

Comment: So... why not simply take the largest values altogether that exceed some "minimum level of interest"?

Comment: Why do you care about "significance"?

Comment: @StephanKolassa it is not possible to establish a static cut-off point because each customer group has a way of spending based on its attributes. In other words, a fixed threshold of $1,000 may be high for a customer in group A, but low for customers in group B. That is why I am looking for a statistic that is calculated dynamically within each distribution.

Comment: @PeterFlom I indicate significantly high because anomalous customers will be offered a cross-sell, so it is not acceptable to send it to the customer who, for example, spends $5 and the upper bound of the IQR in the distribution of their collective is 0.

Comment: So, again, why do you care about *significance*?   Your response to me shows that you should not care about that, but about effect size. Someone who spends $5. could easily be significant.

Comment: I'm with Peter Flom here. You can't have it both ways. If everyone in a group spends 0-1 USD, then someone who spends 10 USD is "significantly different" (using the term "significantly" in a non-rigorous way). And if every one in a different group spends between 0 and 2000 USD, then someone who spends 1000 USD may well be "non-significant", but still worthy of attention. You could use a two-part criterion: someone has to be in the top (say) 5% of their group *and* in the top 5% overall to be picked.

Comment: @PeterFlom I agree that the reference to _significance_ was not the most accurate. Someone who spends 5 dollars is significant by the fact of having chosen the upper bounds IQR criterion, since this bound = 0. So I am simply looking for another bound greater than 0 to, within the positive values, find true outliers.

Comment: "Outlier" is simply a surprising point. It has no formal defnition. There's no test. Just figure out what you want, substantively

Comment: @StephanKolassa if I add condition "_and_ in the top 5% overall", the selection will be made up only with clients from these high-level groups. I am also interested in the extreme cases in these low-level groups, which would not be included in the selection under this criterion. Thank you for your answer and if you come up with any other idea, do not hesitate to tell me about it

Comment: @PeterFlom agree again, outlier is a kind of buzzword. So the only way would be to continue applying the conventional Upper Bound criterion: (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR), and then apply a lower filter by amount spent, although it would be very dependent on the targeted group? Can you consider any alternative that could be generalized to the rest of the groups? Thank you.

Comment: No, no, no.  The option is to make up a number that means something and use that. Don't use statistics, or IQR, or whatever.

Comment: Can you please provide some plots of the histograms, along with some markers of where you think the appropriate cutoff point would be on those histograms? Then it would be possible to propose a computational approach to estimating such a threshold